# rails 3 xml builder exclude nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

There are two models :names and :rat1. Each name may or may not have a rating in rat1. I want to be able to show all of my ratings that exist and just put N/A for those that don't exist.

routes.rb

```
resources :names do
  resource :rat1
end
```

names.rb

```
has_one :rat1
```

rat1.rb

```
belongs_to :names
```

I am currently trying to convert an html table into an xml block that I can export to a javascript table. I want to do the equivalent of this.

```
<%= @name.rat1.rating || 'N/A' %>
```

but when i try

```
xml.tag!("cell", @name.rat1.rating || 'N/A')
```

It doesn't work. If it is nil it throws a nil class error and fails.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, perhaps the evaluation goes wrong because you were missing parentheses:

```
 xml.tag!("cell", (@name.rat1.rating || 'N/A'))
```

**Edit:**

You can do the following:

```
xml.tag!(cell, (@name.rat1.rating.present? then @name.rat1.rating else "N/A" end ))
```

Saves you some lines of code.

```
<%= if @name.rat1.rating.present? then @name.rat1.rating else "N/A" end %>
```

First it checks if @name.rat1.rating is present and if so it renders @name.rat1.rating. It cannot be nil, since you already checked that through the present? method. If @name.rat1.rating is not present it will follow the else condition and return "N/A".

Comment: Is your xml in a format that supports Ruby? For example an index.rss.builder. If not, it might by necessary to use #{@name.rat1.rating || 'N/A'} or <%= @name.rat1.rating || 'N/A' %> to insert your ruby code.

Comment: You could also try to write it the other way around for testing purposes: xml.tag!("cell, ( 'N/A' unless @name.rat1.rating.present? || @name.rat1.rating P.S. Not tested and perhaps a bit too creative

Comment: Nice option. I did test this and it works. The only reason I think i'll stick with the helper method is that I will need to run this .present? check multiple times in many views. I appreciate your help working through this. The inline solution will just be too lengthy for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution ended up being the following. I created a helper method in names_helper.rb

```
def show_rating(rating)
  if rating.present?
     rating.rating
  else
     "N/A"
  end
end
```

and the way I feed it in the xml is

```
xml.tag!("cell", show_rating(name.rat1))
```

This way I check for the present of the rat1 model before trying to pull the .rating value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That works. I was just trying some codes in a test application. Would be nice to have some inline conditional for that xml file. Saves you a method in the controller. Anyway, the important part was indeed to check for presence first.

Comment: I got it in 1 line now (edited my answer), in case you want a shorter version.